# unable to count the occurrence of a guest in 2 different restaurants and display guest name

Tags: sql, oracle

The question im trying to answer is : to find the names of guest who visited more than 2 different restaurants on 15-JUNE-20.

There is a:
Guest table with GID,Gname
Visit table with VID, GID, RESTID, VDATE
Restaurant table with RESTID, RNAME

whenever i tried introducing the groupby i would get the error

```
SELECT GuestN.GID, GuestN.Gname 
FROM GuestN
WHERE GuestN.GID IN (
    SELECT VisitN.GID 
    FROM VisitN
    WHERE VisitN.Vdate = '15-JUN-20' AND VisitN.restID IN (
        SELECT RestaurantN.Restid 
        FROM RestaurantN having count(*)>2));
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Fix the subquery as: `SELECT Restid FROM RestaurantN GROUP BY Restid N having count(*) > 2`.

Answer (score 2):

The table `RestaurantN` is not needed since you have `restID` in the table `VisitN` and you are not interested in the restaurant'a name, but only on their number.
Join `GuestN` to `VisitN`, aggregate and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT g.GID, g.Gname 
FROM GuestN g INNER JOIN VisitN v
ON v.GID = g.GID
WHERE v.Vdate = '15-JUN-20'
GROUP BY g.GID, g.Gname 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.restID) > 2
```

Comment: omg i just realized I didnt thanks alot !

Comment: @Wietlol fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.